# React using Redux-form , post method

Tags: reactjs, post, redux, react-redux, redux-form

*Today I want to post some data in my DB with redux form, I have the values in my console but I don't really understand how to post a new advert*

**EDIT**

Problem solved using     `this.props.getAdverts()` to refresh on submit
and     `this.props.addAdvert()` to post advert in my submit

Any ideas?

There is my code

First i have the action Action :

```
export function addAdvert(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch("adverts", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
  };
}
```

advert form :

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AdvertForm extends Component {
  submit() {
    //this
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name"> Name</label>
          <Field name="name" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="surname">SurName</label>
          <Field name="surname" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

AdvertForm = reduxForm({
  form: "advert"
})(AdvertForm);

export default AdvertForm;
```

My page (adverts) I don't know if that the good way to call the addAdvert Function here

```
//imports

    class Adverts extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          showForm: false
        };
      }
      submit = values => {
        console.log(values); //the console log above
        this.state.addAdvert(values);
        this.props.getAdverts()
      };
      onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showForm: !this.state.showForm });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAdverts();
      }

      render() {
        const { adverts = [] } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>

            //ADVERTSLIST
            <div className="add-advert-btn">
              <Button
                variant="fab"
                onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
                color="primary"
                aria-label="add"
              >
                <AddIcon />
              </Button>
            </div>
            {this.state.showForm && <AdvertForm onSubmit={this.submit} />}

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      adverts: state.todos.adverts
    });

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { getAdverts, addAdvert }
    )(Adverts);
```

Comment: Why are you keeping `submit` function in `Adverts` component in spite of `AdvertForm`? Why don't you just keep the `submit` functionality inside the `AdvertForm` and then pass a value back to `Adverts` component to just show-hide form? Another thing is what's the use of `dispatch` inside `addAdvert`?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing when you call the post api?

Comment: that working when i put addAdvert in my MapStateToProps and i change  addAdvert(values) by this.props.addAdvert(values) but i need to reload the page to show my advert ....

Comment: Solved using     this.props.getAdverts();
 in my  submit :) thanks